# Django Many-To-Many through form with specific queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have the following models `Program` and `Exam` with foregin keys to `University`.

```
class Program(models.Model):
    university = models.ForeignKey(University, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    exams = models.ManyToManyField(Exam, through='ProgramExam')

class Exam(models.Model):
    university = models.ForeignKey(University, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

And they have a many-to-many relation through the model `ProgramExam` which adds extra fields.

```
class ProgramExam(models.Model):
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exam = models.ForeignKey(Exam, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    coef = models.FloatField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(3.0)]
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['program', 'exam']]
```

How do I set the *queryset* in **forms.ModelChoiceField** so to only display instances of `Exam` that have the same *ForeignKey* as the instance of `Program`

```
class ProgramExamForm(forms.ModelForm):
    exam = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Exam.objects.none())
```

I tried passing a queryset in my *view* but it interferes with `request.POST`

```
def create_program(request):
    user = request.user
    exams = user.university.exam_set.all()
    program_exam_form = ProgramExamForm()
    program_form.fields['exam'].queryset = exams


    if user:
        if hasattr(user, 'university'):
            if request.method == 'POST':
                program_exam_form = ProgramExamForm(request.POST)

                if program_exam_form.is_valid():
                    program_exam = program_exam_form.save()
                    ...

            context = {'program_exam_form': program_exam_form}
            return render(request, 'create_program.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the `queryset` after you reinitialize the `ProgramExamForm`:

```py
def create_program(request):
    ...

    if user:
        if hasattr(user, 'university'):
            if request.method == 'POST':
                program_exam_form = ProgramExamForm(request.POST)
                program_form.fields['exam'].queryset = exams  # here
    ...
```

Comment: It still shows as an empty queryset when I visualise the form, because of `exam = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Exam.objects.none())` but if I remove this line it visualises all instances of `Exam` ignoring the queryset.

Comment: so basically i got the names wrong, ive written `program_form` instead of `program_exam_form`. Setting the queryset works fine if you don't mess up your namings (: